# Clarification regarding CRC16 calculation

Tags: c, crc

I am trying to calculate CRC for the first time. I have read a few pages that explain what is crc and how to calculate. Mainly this : https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/implementation-of-crc-checksum-c-crc16-as-an-example.html

I have a code that calculates CRC16

```
uint16_t CalCrc(uint16_t crc_initial, uint8_t* buf,uint16_t len,uint16_t POLY)
{
    unsigned int byte;
    unsigned char k;
    unsigned short ACC,TOPBIT;
    unsigned short remainder = crc_initial;
    TOPBIT = 0x8000;
    for (byte = 0; byte < len; ++byte)
    {
        ACC = buf[byte];
        remainder ^= ACC;
        printf("new remainder = %u \n",remainder);
        for (k = 8; k > 0; --k)
        {
            if (remainder & TOPBIT)
            {
                remainder = remainder << 1;
                remainder = remainder ^ POLY;
            }
            else
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
            }
        }
    }
    remainder = remainder^0x0000;
    printf("result remainder = %02X \n",remainder);
    return remainder;
}
```

and I call it my main.c:

```
    uint8_t crc_buf[5] = {0x05,0x03,0x04,0x08,0x04};
    CalCrc(0xffff,crc_buf,5,0x1021);
```

The result is:

```
result remainder = BDD5
```

As you can see from my function call, I pass 0xffff as initial crc value and 0x1021 as polynomial.

I am trying to confirm if my calculation is correct with some online crc calculators such as:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
https://crccalc.com/

According to the initial and polynomial values that I use, the result should be:
[image]

Could someone help me understand what is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you tracked down the intermediate values and compared them to what is expected by hand?

Comment: Hey @Jean-BaptisteYunès. I am not sure what do you mean. Could you clarify please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bit shift in the calculation. Change:

```c
        ACC = buf[byte];
```

to:

```c
        ACC = (unsigned)buf[byte] << 8;
```

Compare with this C# example code from Sunshine's [Understanding and implementing CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) calculation](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html):

```cs
public static ushort Compute_CRC16_Simple(byte[] bytes)
{
    const ushort generator = 0x1021; /* divisor is 16bit */
    ushort crc = 0; /* CRC value is 16bit */

    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        crc ^= (ushort(b << 8); /* move byte into MSB of 16bit CRC */

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if ((crc & 0x8000) != 0) /* test for MSB = bit 15 */
            {
                crc = (ushort((crc << 1) ^ generator);
            }
            else
            {
                crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

It uses a different initial value to your function, but note the line that XORs the byte into the MSB of the 16-bit CRC:

```cs
        crc ^= (ushort(b << 8); /* move byte into MSB of 16bit CRC */
```

Comment: Damn you must have a big brain to notice such thing! Appreciate that a lot. Although I am not fully understanding why this is required, it seems to return correct CRC (when comparing to online CRC calculator)

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I just compared with the code on the Sunshine's home page (see updated answer). Obviously, this differs from the code you originally found that XORed the new byte into the LSB of the CRC. I need to go through the theory to determine which one is correct!